# How to put String and Integer elements in LinkedHashMap with IntStream?

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I am new to `LinkedHashMap` and I want to put elements `<String, Integer>` in my Map with IntStream instead of filter.put("1", 1)... Is there any way to do it?

```
private Map<String, Integer> filter = new LinkedHashMap<>();

@PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IdNotFoundException {
        filter.put("1", 1);
        filter.put("2", 2);
        filter.put("3", 3);
        filter.put("4", 4);
        filter.put("5", 5);
        filter.put("6", 6);
        filter.put("7", 7);
        filter.put("8", 8);
        filter.put("9", 9);
        filter.put("10", 10);
        filter.put("All", -1);
    }
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by this

Comment: I have to put "1", 1   "2", 2 ... can I do it with lambda instead of using 11 lines of filter.put

Comment: if its always "1",1 why not use a simple loop? for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ filter.put(i,i); }

Comment: Create loop while or for with your `index`

Comment: Where should the initial data come from. The way you write it `"1", 1, "2", 2` sounds like an arbitrary array. But I'm really not sure on how you want to store the initial data? Or is that up to you?

Comment: Why would you use lambda for this? Just a regular loop would do just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, I suggest to use `IntStream`:

```
 Map<String, Integer> filter = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    IntStream.range(1, 11).forEach(integer -> filter.put(String.valueOf(integer), integer));
    filter.put("All", -1);
```